# Page not launching with AngularSeed on Firebase URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angular-seed

I followed in detail the five minute tutorial at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hj0LyZ13D3Q
I executed the following steps:

1. I set up an account at Firebase.com
2. I set up a new app within my Firebase account
3. I opened my terminal and:

   1. sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
   2. firebase login (followed by email and password for firebase.com)
   3. firebase bootstrap
   4. selected the new app as listed from Firebase
   5. chose the angular template
   6. cd to the newly created directory
   7. firebase login

On the video, the new site is up and running at https://newapp.firebaseapp.com
In my case I get nothing but a blank screen and my JS console provides nothing but a series of errors:

```
GET https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/normalize.css  myapp.firebaseapp.com/:9
GET https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/main.css  myapp.firebaseapp.com/:10
GET https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/bower_components/angular/angular.js  myapp.firebaseapp.com/:33
GET https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/bower_components/html5-boilerplate/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js  myapp.firebaseapp.com/:12
GET https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js  myapp.firebaseapp.com/:34
GET https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/bower_components/firebase/firebase.js  myapp.firebaseapp.com/:35
GET https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/bower_components/firebase-simple-login/firebase-simple-login.js  myapp.firebaseapp.com/:36
GET https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js  myapp.firebaseapp.com/:37
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined app.js:4
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined config.js:4
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined controllers.js:5
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined decorators.js:9
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined directives.js:6
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined filters.js:5
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined routes.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined services.js:6
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined firebase.utils.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined simpleLogin.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

I'm using Node v0.10.32, Firebase Command Line Tools Version 1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the tutorial omited the bower angular bower_components. https://github.com/firebase/generator-angularfire

I copied and pasted them from another project and put the corresponding scripts from the other project in the head of my index.html and it works.